# DataFrame: Import semicolon csv file

Tags: ios, dataframe, csv

Hi I am trying to import a **Numbers** exported CSV file into a DataFrame. The CSV has **semicolon** separators.
When i set the options to:

```
let options = CSVReadingOptions(hasHeaderRow: true, delimiter: ";")
do {
       let frame = try DataFrame(contentsOfCSVFile: url, options: options)
       print(frame)
   } catch let error {
       print("\(error)")
   }
```

The app hangs without error on reading the options (delimiter?). When I change the delimiter to a comma the app does not hang but the data is formatted wrong: **1 column with all data of the row, instead of 4 columns**.

```
 ━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃   ┃ Index;Age;Year;Name;;; ┃
┃   ┃ <String>               ┃
┡━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ 0 │ 1;44;1982;Jansen;;;    │
│ 1 │ 2;66;1977;Piet;;;      │
│ 2 │ 3;99;1952;Klaas;;;     │
│ 3 │ 4;71;2020;Willem;;;    │
└───┴────────────────────────┘
4 rows, 1 column
```

trace:

```
Thread 1 Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0  0x00000001df418140 in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol1035 ()
#1  0x00000001df47ab00 in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol3177 ()
#2  0x00000001df47a760 in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol3176 ()
#3  0x00000001df47a16c in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol3174 ()
#4  0x0000000104b64454 in AppDelegate.application(_:open:options:) at /Users/kaasCoder/Documents/Documenten - MacBook Pro/Developer/ Dev-Apps/DataApp.4.1.9_1/DataApp/AppDelegate.swift:121
#5  0x0000000104b64dac in @objc AppDelegate.application(_:open:options:) ()
```

Anyone have a idea how to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Right, my question was all wrong, there was nothing wrong with CSVReadingOptions. I had to move the file to the temp directory and everything works fine. Tank you for you patience.